# tf.gradient with respect to looping variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to calculate a derivative of computation w.r.t. loop variable inside tf.while_loop and apparently, it's not possible.
Toy example:

```
x = tf.Variable(10)
fx = tf.square(x) #possibly very complicated function

def cond(x):
    return tf.not_equal(x, 0)

def body(x):
    return  tf.cond(tf.gradients(fx, x)[0] > 0, lambda: x-1, lambda: x+1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    o = sess.run(tf.while_loop(cond, body, [x]))
    print(o)
```

running the above code yield:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

The reason (as much as I understand) is that the variable x inside the loop is not a node in my global function fx.

How can I fix this issue? one idea is adding fx to the loop variables but I couldn't find a way to maintain it without entirely reconstruct the computation graph in every loop.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
The following changes solves it:

change the function:

```
def f(x):
    return tf.square(x) #possibly very complicated function
```

and change the body:

```
def body(x):
    return  tf.cond(tf.gradients(f(x), x)[0] > 0, lambda: x-1, lambda: x+1)
```

But this solution rebuilds graph in every iteration which might be inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution is to simply use assign with control dependency:

```
x = tf.Variable(10)
fx = tf.square(x) #possibly very complicated function

def cond(x_i):
    return tf.not_equal(x_i, 0)

def body(x_i):
    update_x = tf.assign(x,x_i)
    with tf.control_dependencies([update_x]):
        return  tf.cond(tf.gradients(fx, x)[0] > 0, lambda: x_i-1, lambda: x_i+1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    o = sess.run(tf.while_loop(cond, body, [x]))
    print(o)
```